# Issue making post request to Facebook open graph API

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, angularjs, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm trying to post on an Event wall on a user's behalf. I have the publish_stream permission but am having trouble making a post request.

This doesn't work:

```
$http.post("#{url}/#{id}/feed", {message: message, access_token: token})
```

But these do:

1)

```
$http.get("#{url}/#{id}/feed?method=POST&message=#{message}&access_token=#{token}")
```

2)

```
$http.post "#{url}/#{id}/feed?access_token=#{token}&message=#{message}"
```

Any idea why the Facebook API would accept the latter but reject the post method (like the API requires)? The error I get with the $http.post is "this method requires an access_token"

Answer (score 0):

I have limited idea about Facebook API but it seems that `post` method on `$http` is designed to send the data in the request body, whereas access token i think needs to be provided in querystring. `post` method would to parameter mapping for the url if the you provide it gets the same name token as here

```
$http.post("#{url}/#{id}/feed?access_token=#{token}&message=#{message}", {message: message, access_token: token})
```

Comment: why add access_token and message in both the query string and request body?

Comment: Yes i think angular does this, need to check why does it do it.